# How to Create Model with Notifiable Trait

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification

I want create a Model with Notifiable feature,

First,in my controller :

```
$collection = collect([
    [
    'name' => 'user1',
    'email' => 'user1@gmail.com',
    ],
    [
    'name' => 'user2',
    'email' => 'user2@gmail.com',
    ],
    [
    'name' => 'user1000',
    'email' => 'user1000@gmail.com',
   ],
 ]);

 $u3 = new User3($collection);
```

when I return $u3->getEmailList();  , output is :

```
[{"name":"user1","email":"user1@gmail.com"},{"name":"user2","email":"user2@gmail.com"},{"name":"user1000","email":"user1000@gmail.com"}]
```

my class for User3 is:

```
namespace App;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications;
use Notifications\EmailClientOfAccount;

class User3 extends User
{
   use Notifiable;
   public $emailList;

  public function __construct($emails)
  {
        $this->emailList = $emails;

  }

  public  function getEmailList()
    {
     return $this->emailList;
    }
   public function routeNotificationForMail($notification)
   {
    return $this->emailList['email'];
   }
 }
```

Then, I pass $u3 to Notification as:

```
Notification::send($u3->getEmailList(), new
```

SendMailNotification($template,$subject,$request->input('mailFromTitle'),$attachments));

It show below error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function routeNotificationFor() on array
```

can you help me for solve this problem,Please?

Thanks in Advance,

//-------------------
I correct to :

Notification::send($u3, new SendMailNotification($template,$subject,$request->input('mailFromTitle'),$attachments));

In my My Notification:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
return  new EmailTo($notifiable,$this->view,$this->topic,$this- 
      >mailFrom,$this->attaches);
}
```

and  in Build():

```
public function build()
    {

        $email= $this->view($this->view);
        return $email;
    }
```

But it not work,  I dont know where is mistake?

Comment: hard to help without an error message.

Comment: I'm sorry, i pass a collection to User3 and return same collection, and pass output that is a collection  to first my  notification argument, is it right?

Comment: Only pass models if you want it done on more than one we can figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification send expects a Notifiable object, not the email list itself, if you change it to this, you should get further.

```
Notification::send($u3, new SendMailNotification($template,$subject,$request->input('mailFromTitle'),$attachments));
```